# passing data through window.location in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass the data through window.location, the data is available in del(id,img,album).

I want to send multiple values through window.location as

```
 window.location="save.php?type=deldownload&album="+album&id="+id;
```

But this does not work, but this code below works.

```
function del(id,img,album){
    var where_to= confirm("Do you really want to delete "+img+" image");
    if (where_to== true)
    {
         window.location="save.php?type=deldownload&id="+id; 
    } 
    else
    {
         alert('Ok! You Can continue with this Album');
    }

}
```

Please tell what the real problem is.

Answer (score 6):

You missing few quotes

```
window.location="save.php?type=deldownload&album="+album+"&id="+id;
```