# how to navigate from angular to php page after $http.post()

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http

Now I have a php page "userreq.php" managed by a angular js controller.On a button click I am calling a funcion which posts the data to another php page "checkout.php".

```
$http({
        url: "checkout.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data: variable
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is how I am posting it.Now I want the page to navigate to  checkout.php after the variable has been posted so that I can work with that variable in checkout.php. How can I achieve that.

Comment: you could use window.location.href = 'url'; in your success function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: but it is redirection right http post will have no effect..I am new to angular so I may be wrong

Comment: depends on what you want, you could simply pass params with window.location instead of using ajax

Comment: $scope.checkout = function(){
         $http({
         url:"checkout.php",
         method : 'POST',
         data :{
            total:$scope.total
        },
       
        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.location.href="checkout.php";
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log("not done");
});
    } and in checkout.php i am doing <?php $var = $_POST['total'];?> but i am getting error that total is not defined

Comment: could you provide me with example of passing params with window.location.href

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12527279/2460773

Comment: thanks for the help sir..but actually i need to pass an array

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` in your controller and pass your data as query parameters.

Example :

```
var url = 'checkout.php'; 
var data = { id: 1, name: 'foo' };

$http({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data
})
.success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    window.location.href = url + '?' + $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);
});
```

And in your php, retrieve the data from `$_GET` :

```
$field = $_GET[$field];
// Output: array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo' )
```

Comment: If you want use POST rather than GET see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data